# ESLINT errors ( Error '$' is not defined)

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have **Brackets** installed, and i getting ESLINT error, as far as i know i dont have ESLINT installed

[image: Code and the error]

That is the first time i get this error, my question is, how do i install ESLINT and configure it that i don't receive the errors. ( The JavaScript code is copied from CODEPEN so it should be ok)

The main problem is ESLINt, i tried with other JS plugins and get the same error, as i said its the first time im getting this error.

Comment: So add Global reference to it

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `'$'` to the `globals` object inside your `.eslintrc` file.

## Like so:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "globals": {
        "$": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure it to allow globals:

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Either comment on top of the file

```
/* global $ */
```

or in the config